# Restrict entries into broker database when multimedia components are published in tridion

Tags: 2013, publishing

We have a requirement , when a multimedia component is published in Tridion the component entries should not enter the broker database and the images, files etc should reach the respective storage location.

In what way can we achieve this requirement??

Comment: I think Saurabh understands your requirement, but to be clear, by "storage" you mean file system? You'll find in the Storage Configuration "Storage" could mean "filesystem" or database ("persistence").

Comment: The awkward phrase is "the component entries should not enter the broker database". When publishing binaries, it's usual to have the binary itself go to the file system, but various metadata about it is stored in the broker database. (OK - it's still possible to use the file system for the metadata as well, but it's already deprecated.)

Comment: Yeah Alvin, the question was not clear. I guessed a bit, what kind of issue a new user could have ignoring the confusing words/statement. To make it clear I started my answer saying "So If you want to deploy your Multimedia (Images\files) to File System".

Answer (score 2):

So If you want to deploy your Multimedia (Images\files) to File System. It is controlled by your Deployer Configuration (cd_storage_conf.xml). Please find the cd_storage_conf.xml file in your Deployer Application and set the Binaries to be deployed on to the Filesystem in it.

To do so, you need to de the following:

1. add a storage element for Filesystem as a child of storages element.

   `<Storages>
       <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="storageFS" defaultFilesystem="false">
       <Root Path="C:\myFsLocation" />
       </Storage>
   </Storages>`
2. and use it to configure you binary item type to be deployed to filesystem as below:

`<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="{defaultStorageId}" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="storageFS" cached="false"/> 
</ItemTypes>`

To know more about configuration of storage, visit this [link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D7B8D088-0AD3-4652-9A61-BC86B25D04CE).

Comment: Is "Deployer Configuration" the right descirption here (e.g. does it include both `cd_deployer_conf.xml` and `cd_storage_conf.xml`)?

Comment: Sometimes we talk of the Deployer and mean just the sub-system that is configured by cd_deployer_conf.xml - other times we mean the complete server responsible for deployment. This latter sense obviously includes a storage sub-system and its configuration file.

Comment: @Saurabh thank you for the reply... we have the same configuration as specified in your comment above . When we publish the multimedia component the images are available in the file system as expected. But the details w.r.t to the component enter into the broker database as well for example the BINARYVARIANTS table or CUSTOM_META table.    We would like to restrict the entry in the above mentioned tables and just make sure the image alone is available at the file system.

Comment: I am interested to know, why do you want to restrict the entry in to the tables? Well, the information stored in the tables are used by tridion to manage the binaries at CD side. AFAIK, I don't think it's possible to restrict entries in the tables as it's Tridion core functionality . Please Update your question to get the helpful answers.